# Sorting by duration of audio file not working

Tags: javascript, html

So I tried to make a sorting function that sorts audio files by their duration, following this example:

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table

In my code the first column of the table contains names of audio files. In the second column there are playable html audio players. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l97Qf.png) is a picture. So I tried to sort these players by the duration of the audio that they contain. With the following function:

```
function sortByDuration() {
    var rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
    var table = document.getElementById("table-design");
    switching = true;
    /*Make a loop that will continue until
    no switching has been done:*/
    while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            //start by saying there should be no switching:
            shouldSwitch = false;

            /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
            one from current row and one from the next:*/

            /*NOTE: The id's of the audio players start from 0*/
            /*Eg.: player0, player1, ... , playern*/

            /*Getting the current player*/
            var k = i - 1;
            var playerName1 = "player" + k;
            x = document.getElementById(playerName1);

            /*Getting the audio's duration from the player*/
            var durationTemp = x.duration.toFixed(0);
            var duration = parseInt(durationTemp);

            /*Getting the next player*/
            var playerName2 = "player" + i;
            y = document.getElementById(playerName2);
            var durationTemp2 = y.duration.toFixed(0);
            var duration2 = parseInt(durationTemp2);

            /*I tried and it loads the first two values*/
            alert(duration);
            alert(duration2);

            //check if the two rows should switch place:
            if (duration > duration2) {
                //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
            and mark that a switch has been done:*/
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);

            switching = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this function is almost the same one like the *sort-by-name* function, but modified to compare the length in seconds of the audio files. My problem is that, it goes into an infinite loop, I checked the indexing, and tried to modify here and there but I can't seem to find why isn't it working well. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Any reason you're writing your own sorting logic instead of using `Array.sort`?

Comment: Do you use chrome are you getting any errors?

Comment: @whiterabbitj Yes I am using Chrome, I don't get any errors but it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @BenWest Not really, I was wondering if this is possible.

Comment: is the console outputting correctly  rows.length

Comment: @whiterabbitj yes

Comment: are your player names and duration get outputted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a tangent for your question since that relates to why your code isn't halting, but I had a little empty time and wrote a slightly more easily modular example of table sorting that uses the `<array>.sort(comparator)` built-in.

It's a departure from the w3schools model you're basing off but probably applicable with a little tag and id massaging in the selectors, so you or someone else might find it useful all the same.

```js
/*
    Example of a simple and a little overly verbose
    sorting set-up for <audio> elements in a table
    according to variable rules.

    This example links to royalty free music
    by Kevin MacLeod <https://incompetech.com>
*/

function songs_from_document() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table-design");
  var row_list = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var row_count = row_list.length;
  var rows = [];
  for (var ix = 1; ix < row_count; ++ix) {
    var row = row_list[ix];
    var audio = row.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    var title = row.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
    rows.push({
      row: row,
      audio: audio,
      title: title
    });
  }
  return rows;
}

function name_comparer_asc(song1, song2) {
  return song1.title.innerHTML.localeCompare(song2.title.innerHTML);
}

function name_comparer_desc(song1, song2) {
  return song2.title.innerHTML.localeCompare(song1.title.innerHTML);
}

function duration_comparer_asc(song1, song2) {
  return song1.audio.duration - song2.audio.duration;
}

function duration_comparer_desc(song1, song2) {
  return song2.audio.duration - song1.audio.duration;
}

function sort_songs(comparer) {
  var songs = songs_from_document().sort(comparer);
  var count = songs.length;
  var table = document.getElementById("table-design");
  while (table.childElementCount > 1) {
    table.removeChild(table.lastChild);
  }
  for (var ix = 0; ix < count; ++ix) {
    table.appendChild(songs[ix].row);
  }
}

function populate_table() {
  var songs = [
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Black%20Bird.mp3",
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Aftermath.mp3",
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Light%20Awash.mp3",
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Ashton%20Manor.mp3",
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Backbay%20Lounge.mp3",
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Living%20Voyage.mp3",
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Bet%20You%20Can%20ver%202.mp3",
    "https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Land%20of%20the%20Dead.mp3"
  ];
  var table = document.getElementById("table-design");
  while (table.childElementCount > 1) {
    table.removeChild(table.lastChild);
  }
  for (let i = 0, n = songs.length; i < n; ++i) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let td1 = document.createElement("td");
    let td2 = document.createElement("td");
    let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    let audio = document.createElement("audio");

    h3.innerHTML = unescape(songs[i].split("/").slice(-1));
    audio.setAttribute("controls", "true");
    audio.setAttribute("src", songs[i]);
    audio.setAttribute("type", "audio/mpeg");

    td1.appendChild(h3);
    td2.appendChild(audio);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>audio sort</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="populate_table()">populate table</button>
  <button onclick="sort_songs(name_comparer_asc)">by name asc</button>
  <button onclick="sort_songs(name_comparer_desc)">by name desc</button>
  <button onclick="sort_songs(duration_comparer_asc)">by duration asc</button>
  <button onclick="sort_songs(duration_comparer_desc)">by duration desc</button>
  <table id="table-design">
    <tr>
      <td><u>Song Title</u></td>
      <td><u>Audio Player</u></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I will accept this as an answer, even though it doesn't solve my error. It gives a working and better alternative for the approach. So if anyone faces the same problem in the future, here is a good solve.